# Как сбросить wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

Как сбросить функцию wp_query при нажатии на вывод рубрики ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'post_price',
    'meta_query' => array(
      'key' => 'post_price',
      'value' => '0',
      'compare' => '>',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
        'suppress_filters' => false,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

    );
 ?>
 <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php  if ($query->have_posts()) { while ($query->have_posts()) {$query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="catalogSec-Item">
        <div class="catalogSec-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thambnail' ) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="catalogSec-descript">
            <p class="catalogSec-descript__name"><?php echo get_short_title(36); ?></p>
            <!-- <p class="catalogSec-descript__functional"><?php // the_category( $separator = '/', ''); ?></p> -->
            <p class="catalogSec-descript__price"><?php the_field('post_price'); ?> Руб.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="catalogSec-descript-btn">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-blue catalogSec-descript__btn">Купить</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } // конец while ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
<?php }  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в слова "сбросить функцию wp_query"? Удалить её из WordPress :) ? Да и функции такой нет, в том числе и в вашем коде. Выразите свою мысль, пожалуйста, так, чтобы вас можно было понять.

Comment: В функции я использую фильтр на основе wp_query, но при нажатии на рубрику не выводятся рубрики

Comment: Как это все связано с приведенным кодом и картинкой!

Comment: в том что при попадании на страницу каталога, выводятся посты по фильтру wp_query, но при нажатии на рубрику слева фильтр ни как себя не ведет, а надо вывести рубрики с фильтром по кастомной цене

Comment: Что это за фильтр? Чем реализован? Где его код? Как нажатие на кнопку фильтра связано в приведенным кодом?